# Labeling and formatting issues for Decision Trees in R

Tags: r, tree, decision-tree

I am trying to do a tree for a large dataset that I have. I can run the tree fine and receive no error. However, when I look at the labels for the tree they are very messy and not legible. Additionally, I feel the results are not correct. (FYI, I took out some of the variables in the code below so not just scrolling through all the variables, the problem happens with many or just a couple of variables)

For example,the EMPLOY1 split is on =j, but the values in the variables are "unable to work", "retired", etc. Any thoughts what I am doing wrong with the tree output?

Code:

```
library(rpart)
dc <- cdc[which(cdc$POORHLTH != '77'),] # excludes 17 obs
cdc <- cdc[which(cdc$POORHLTH != '99'),] # excludes 6 obs
cdc <- cdc[which(cdc$POORHLTH != '.'),] # excludes 999 obs
cdc$poorhealth_num <- as.numeric(as.character(cdc$POORHLTH))
# as.numeric(cdc$POORHLTH) # does not work b/c it turns 0 into 2 and 30 into 21
cdc$poorhealth_cat <- ifelse(cdc$poorhealth_num<2, 1, 0)
fit <- rpart(poorhealth_cat ~
SCNTWRK1+
SCNTLWK1+
SCNTMEAL+
SCNTMONY+
SCNTPAID+
SEX+
SLEPTIM1+
SMOKE100+
SMOKDAY2+
STRENGTH+
TOLDHI2+
USENOW3+
WEIGHT2+
WTCHSALT+
FRT16+
, method="class", data=cdc) # grow tree
printcp(fit) # display the results
plotcp(fit) # visualize cross-validation results
summary(fit) # detailed summary of split

# plot unpruned tree
plot(fit,uniform=TRUE, main="Classification Tree for poorhealth_cat")
```

[image]

Comment: Not reproducible. No cdc data object found and the trailing "=" sign in the formula should have thrown an error.

Comment: @BondedDust I am happy to provide the dataset, however, I am not sure how to do that in this forum. If you tell me how, I will be happy to do so.

Comment: There are "dropbox" facilities on the Interweb that people often use when they do not have a local website or ftp server handy. And I see I failed to synchronized my shift key with my =/+ key.

Comment: @BondedDust Here is the link to dropbox:https://www.dropbox.com/s/utumdn9a8ar280f/LLCP2013v9b.csv?dl=0

the model does work with the + sign too.

Comment: Well, it throws an error on my device and furthermore `rpart` is misspelled. AND even more problematic there is no 'poorhealth_cat' variable.

Comment: @BondedDust I included some of the code to how I got there. I changed a bunch of the code when I wrote into this forum because there were many more variables and to save on space. So sorry for any mis-splellings but I think it gets the general idea across

Comment: I'm giving up. Still getting errors, this time: object 'SCNTWRK1' not found. And as far as I can tell most of the terms in that modle are not in the names of the 'cdc' object. `trim(nams) %in% names(cdc)  ###
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[11]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`